Why is permission error returned when sending creating FileResponse in Django?
In temp folder there is a temporary file called video.mp4 which is meant to be created, then sent to user as attachment and then deleted. The following code returns PermissionError: [WinError 32] for this line: os.remove(file_path). Why ? Am i deleting file too early ?
def download_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        link_input_data = request.POST.get('link_input_field')  # todo change to use django forms later
        download_cda.start_download(link_input_data)
        file_path = "temp\\" + "video.mp4"
        response = None
        try:
            file = open(file_path, "rb")
            response = FileResponse(file, as_attachment=True, filename="video.mp4")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)  # todo add exception code
        finally:
            os.remove(file_path)
        return response
    else:
        form = UrlForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {"url_form": form})

I couldn't find anything for this in docs: [FileResponse]
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse)

Likely because the file is not yet closed. The result is streamed, so the file is not yet finished when the response is starting to be returned.

indeed, since again, it streams the response, and furthermore Windows does not allow removing opened files.

How can i wait for response to finish streaming to safely delete file ?

@Szymon42214 you can try to use context manager, so it can be closed automatically when it finishes

@Szymon42214: well the easiest way would be to use a Unix-based file system, since you can remove an opened file, and then the OS thus will solve that issue by postponing the real removal until the handlers are closed, and unlink already :).

@user70: that will not help, if that works, it will simply block the response, since that works in a streaming way, so reading the next chunk later in the process.

I tried using context manager and received ValueError: read of closed file

@Szymon42214: yes, since the FileResponse does not immediately reads the file, it streams the file...


Why ? Am i deleting file too early ?

Yes, because a FileResponse [Django-doc] works in a streaming manner: it reads a chunk of the file, passes that to the client, then reading the next chunk, etc. If you return the response, the file is thus not yet completely read.
We can use the _resource_closers list of the response, to remove the file:
def download_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        link_input_data = request.POST.get(
            'link_input_field'
        )  # todo change to use django forms later
        download_cda.start_download(link_input_data)
        file_path = 'temp\\' + 'video.mp4'
        response = None
        def closer():
            return os.remove(file_path)
        try:
            response = FileResponse(
                open(file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename='video.mp4'
            )
            response._resource_closers.append(closer)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)  # todo add exception code
            closer()
    form = UrlForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'url_form': form})
But serving files with Django is however often not a good idea. Usually what you do is let the webserver like Nginx or Apache serve the file. For Nginx with an X-Accel-Redirect header [nginx-doc].
In this case you can even add a post_action in nginx, to remove the file after Nginx served the file.
